# How to translate “L’être unique a plus d’un nom” in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I was reading about an eclectic mausoleum in Belgium. It is written in four languages (Greek, Sanskrit, Egyptian and French) the following sentence:

> L’être unique a plus d’un nom.

> ΕΙΣ Δ ΩΝ ΠΟΛΥΩΝΥΜΟΣ ΕΣΤΙ (if I transcribed it correctly)

[image: Egyptian]
[image: Greek]
[image: Sanskrit]

That is:

> The unique being has more than one name.

How do you translate that into (classical) Latin?

I was thinking something like

> Unicum ens plus quam unum nomen habet

But I'm sure you can do better

Comment: Any chance you have the Greek, Egyptian, and Sanskrit translations?

Comment: @cmw Sure, I added them to the question

Comment: Thanks! It's interesting to see what they opted for.

Answer (score 2):

*Ens* is tricky because it is mediaeval rather than classical, invented to convey ΤΟ ΟΝ.

Given that the style of lapidary inscriptions is, well, lapidary, my first attempt would be

> Nomina unici plurima

where the adjective “unicum” is promoted to a noun - thus from “one and only” to “the One and Only”.

If you allowed yourself *ens* then you could have

```
Entis unici nomina plurima
```

“Of the unique entity the names are many”

Comment: You didn’t ask, and I’m not expert enough, but myself I’d have saved chisels and said πολυώνυμον το μόνον. But don’t trust me on this.